# Join tables and save the result in an ArrayList-Attribute

Tags: java, mysql, arraylist, mybatis

Every customer can have multiple driving licence classes. As example: Customer John can have the classes A, B and C. There is a table Customer, DrivingLicence and DrivingLicenceCustomer.

The select statement looks like this (in my mapper):

```
<select id="selectCustomer" resultType="CustomerDTO">
    SELECT *
    FROM Customer c
    INNER JOIN DrivingLicenseCustomer d
    ON c.CustomerID = d.Customer
</select>
```

The result could be:

```
+------------+-------+---------------------+
| CustomerId | Name  | DrivingLicenceClass |
+------------+-------+---------------------+
|          1 | John  | A                   |
|          1 | John  | B                   |
|          1 | John  | C                   |
|          2 | Clara | A                   |
|          3 | Sarah | C                   |
+------------+-------+---------------------+
```

The class for the customer looks like this:

```
public class CustomerDTO {
    private int customerId;
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<String> drivingLicences;
    //....
}
```

As you can see in the result above: There are multiple rows with the same customer (every row represents an object). Currently my implementation is not able to map the DrivingLicenceClass correcly. The result should look like this:

```
+------------+-------+---------------------+
| CustomerId | Name  | DrivingLicenceClass |
+------------+-------+---------------------+
|          1 | John  | {A, B, C}           |
|          2 | Clara | {A}                 |
|          3 | Sarah | {C}                 |
+------------+-------+---------------------+
```

Is it possible to fill the ArrayList automatically by my MyBatis-Mapper?
Thanks alot!!!

Comment: This would have been simple with Hibernate mapping but in pure sql I cant think of a better way than using a map with key as customer name and value a customer obj and checking for each row if it exist in the map and if it does to return the object; add the driver license to the set and put it back in the map.After that you build the array with what's in the map.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: mySQL. I tried to use the "Nested Select for Collection" (https://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html) but it does not work for me and I'm not sure if I'm on the right way with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with the following code:

```
for (CustomerDTO customerDTO : customerList) {
        List<DrivingLicence> licenceList = s.selectList("selectDrivingLicencesByCustomer", customerDTO.getCustomerId());
}
```

(Select the drivingLicence for each customer)

But that's not really the way I want to do it. If there is a better way, please let me know.